# Convert TL Language (mtproto) type to C#

Tags: c#, telegram, mtproto

I am using tl-language compiler to compile schema of Telegram Api TL language described in https://core.telegram.org/mtproto in C#

There is a compiler that compile tl-language to C# classes https://github.com/everbytes/SharpTL.Compiler

But it can compile new telegram schema at this line:

```
"params":[
    {"name":"flags","type":"#"},
    {"name":"report_spam","type":"flags.0?true"}]
,"type":"PeerSettings"}
```

And it compile it to wrong code:

```
[TLObject(0x818426CD)]
public partial class PeerSettings : IPeerSettings
{
    [TLProperty(1)]
    public I# Flags { get; set; }

    [TLProperty(2)]
    public IFlags0?true ReportSpam { get; set; }

}
```

Is there any solution in casting in C# codes?

I do not know what is type of this "flags:#" in C#

This type "#" described in https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL-formal

```
user {flags:#} id:flags.0?string first_name:flags.1?string last_name:flags.2?string reserved3:flags.3?False reserved4:flags.4?False = User flags;
```

In the future, bits 3 and 4 in the flags field may be used to transmit new fields after changing the names and types of the reserved3 and reserved4 fields

Comment: It seems like the property is an enumerable of IFlags: "public IFlags { get; set; }" given "#" seems to define the set of IFlag types/values.

Comment: flag# is integer type used as a flag to indicate which flagged-fields are present (on receiving) or which flagged-fields you are including(on sending)

Answer (score 1):

this means `int` according to TLGenerator

Answer (score 1):

```
peerSettings#818426cd flags:# report_spam:flags.0?true = PeerSettings
```

deep searching around this I think this hash (#) means that dynamic value of variable, in some  cases it can be true or false, another cases it can be a  sequence of integers nonnegative:

```
matrix {X:Type} m:# n:# a:(%Tuple (%Tuple X m) n) = Matrix X;
```

above we got the M and N taking a integer random value > 0

```
get_users req_fields:# ids:%(Vector int) = Vector %(User req_fields)
```

in this another case it can assume a conditional value
req_fields variable is cast only to User object, but in other cases it could be casted
to another kind of object.

maybe the correct way of this TLObject in c# is :

```
[TLObject(0x818426CD)]
public partial class PeerSettings : IPeerSettings
{
    [TLProperty(1)]
    public int Flags { get; set; }

    [TLProperty(2)]
    public bool ReportSpam { get; set; }

}
```

apologises my english is rusty